# webpack 5 adds defer="defer" to script tags?

Tags: webpack, expose-loader

my html document's head tag has in it:

```
<script src="/packs/vendors-node_modules_jquery_dist_jquery_js-exposed-e9b29cc0e77d15c93346.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

and in the document's body, I have a script tag which is trying to use jQuery, but I get the error that `$ is undefined.`

How can I make it so that expose-loader does not put that defer tag on jQuery so that it's available when my script tag is executed?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and finally solved it by installing [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and adding a custom-webpack.config.js file with the following configuration:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  scriptLoading: 'blocking',
}),
```

This config removed the defer="defer" from my scripts.